# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTimeOffset?' to 'System.DateTimeOffset'.An explicit conversion exits(are you missing a cast)

Tags: c#

I am still learning C# .NET libraries how do I handle the following case. If anyone can guide me in the right directions it will be highly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You should write `livestoekWeightDocket.MovementDate.GetValueOrDefault();` this would return default value of DateTimeOffset if MovementDate is Null else it will return whatever value it has.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that it can't assign a possible `null` value to a `DateTimeOffset`. If you use `GetValueOrDefault()`, it will return a non-null result (the default value of `DateTimeOffset` if the actual value is `null`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't assign a null value to a non-nullable value. One way to fix this is to add your default (non-null) value using `??`.

e.g.

```
MovementDate = livestockWeightDocket.MovementDate ?? DateTimeOffset.MinValue
```